Why can’t I get data from context.user_data[] (I get None) using ConversationHandler in python-telegram-bot
I recently started learning python-telegram-bot. Looking at the example in https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/conversationbot2.py it was decided to write something, this is what happened:
import re

from telegram import Update, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import (
Application,
MessageHandler,
filters,
CallbackQueryHandler,
ConversationHandler,
ContextTypes,
CallbackContext,
)
from text_const import *
from utils.helpers import *


user_data = {}
FULLNAME, EMAIL, NOTES, COMPANIES = range(4)

async def cancel_deal(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
  await update.message.reply_text("Bye!")
  return ConversationHandler.END


async def request_fullname_for_deal_handle(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
  await update.message.reply_text(STATE_FOR_NOTES_WHEN_AUTH,
            parse_mode='HTML')
  return FULLNAME


async def first_response(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
  answer = update.message.text
  if answer.lower() in [CANCEL_HANDLE]:
      await cancel_deal(update, context) 
      return ConversationHandler.END   
  elif len(answer.split()) != 3:
      await update.message.reply_text(NOT_CORRECT_FIO_STATE_TO_DEAL,
            parse_mode='HTML')
      return FULLNAME

  context.user_data['fullname'] = f'{answer}'
  await update.message.reply_text(STATE_FOR_EMAIL,
            parse_mode='HTML')
  return EMAIL


async def second_response(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
  answer = update.message.text
  email = answer.strip()
  if not re.match(r"[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+", email):
      await update.message.reply_text(NOT_CORRECT_EMAIL_STATE_TO_DEAL,
              parse_mode='HTML')
      return EMAIL

  context.user_data['email'] = f'{answer}'
  await update.message.reply_text(STATE_FOR_NOTES,
            parse_mode='HTML')
  return NOTES


async def third_response(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
  answer = update.message.text
  context.user_data['notes'] = f'{answer}'
  db = await init_firebase()
  companies_ref = db.collection("comp").stream()
  inline_keyboard, callback_data_list = await create_inline_keyboard(comp_ref)

  await update.message.reply_text(STATE_FOR_CHOICE_COMPANY_AUTH,
            parse_mode='HTML', 
            reply_markup=inline_keyboard)

  print(f"fio after input: {context.user_data.get('fullname')}")
  print(f"email after input: {context.user_data.get('email')}")
  print(f"Notes after input: {context.user_data.get('notes')}")
  return COMPANIES


async def fourth_response(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    
  db = await init_firebase()
  company_ref = db.collection("comp").document(update.callback_query.data)


  client_ref = db.collection("client").where("telegram_id", "==", update.callback_query.message.chat.id).stream()
    for client in client_ref:
        if client.to_dict().get('tenant_id').id == update.callback_query.data:
            pass
        else:
            context.user_data["comp"] = company_ref
            
  else:
    context.user_data["comp"] = company_ref

  col_ref = db.collection("crm").where("tenant", "==", comp_ref).stream()

  # Format the output
  companies_info = f"Companies: {context.user_data.get('companies')}"
  notes_info = f"Notes: {context.user_data.get('notes')}"
  notess_info = f"fio: {context.user_data.get('fullname')}"
  notesss_info = f"email: {context.user_data.get('email')}"

  # Collecting CRM settings information
  crm_settings_info = "CRM Settings:\n"
  for doc in col_ref:
    crm_settings_info += f"- {doc.id}: {doc.to_dict()}\n"

  # Combine all information into a single message
  final_message = f"{notes_info}\n{companies_info}\n{crm_settings_info}\n{notess_info}\n{notesss_info}"

  await update.callback_query.message.reply_text(final_message)
  return ConversationHandler.END


 # FSM
conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
    entry_points= 
[MessageHandler(filters.Regex(f"^{REQUEST_FULLNAME_FOR_DEAL_HANDLE}$"), request_fullname_for_deal_handle)],
    states={
        FULLNAME: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, first_response)],
        EMAIL: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, second_response)],
        NOTES: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, third_response)],
        COMPANIES: [CallbackQueryHandler(fourth_response)]
    },
    fallbacks=[MessageHandler(filters.Regex(f"^{CANCEL_HANDLE}$"), cancel_deal)]
)

Sorry that the code includes similar functions.
In these lines:
 print(f"fio after input: {context.user_data.get('fullname')}")
 print(f"email after input: {context.user_data.get('email')}")
 print(f"Notes after input: {context.user_data.get('notes')}")

We get this answer:
fio after input: None # test test test
email after input: None # test@test.test
Notes after input: test # test

When receiving callbackquery, the last state, I receive a message from the bot:
Notes: None
Companies: <google.cloud.firestore_v1.document.DocumentReference object at 
  ...>
CRM Settings:
- ...: {'tenant': 
  <google.cloud.firestore_v1.document.DocumentReference object at ...>, 
  'col': []}

fio: None
email: None

Why can't I get context.user_data[] correctly in the next state or upon exiting it? Provided that the data from the last state (received via callback) works correctly
